# How do I create a non localhost connection with MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I'm currently hosting a small website on my college domain where people can fill out a form and post it to database.  I'm trying to figure out how I can set up/edit my MySQL so that its not localhost.

This is the current setting:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8g30.png

Obviously when people fill out the form right now it fails since my MySQL is on localhost.  I tried setting the host name to my IP but that didn't work as well.

Comment: So can users see the form but just get errors when the application attempts to connect to the database? Or have you not yet even configured that far?

Comment: Not enough information here to help you. Where is the form/application hosted?

Comment: "It didn't work" is not a useful explanation of what you need help with.  What *exactly* happens, including the specific error message, when you try to connect to your IP address and the default port, 3306 (unless you deliberately configured MySQL to be on a different port)?

Answer (score 1):

If I have understand you, what you want is to connect to your mysql server, from another PC different of which is running your mysql service. 
In that case, what you need to enter in the Hostname, is the IP address of your mysql server.

Comment: How do I find out what the IP address of my MySQL server is?

Comment: Edit:  I've tried using the IP of my computer where I currently run MySQL but that didn't work.  Is there a specific port I have to use?

Comment: Do you have an online host for your MySQL?

Comment: Yes, its hosted on my computer that I'm currently using.

Comment: Anyone????  There has got to be a way to do this....

Comment: Nick, is important to know where is installed MySQL, and from where do you want to connect to MySQL. **If both things are in the same machine**, you can use "localhost" as hostname. If MySQL is installed and running from another machine, you have to specify the ip of this remote machine as hostname.